# Cannot convert value of type '(AFMultipartFormData!) -> Void' to expected argument type '((AFMultipartFormData?) -> Void)!'

Tags: swift

I am trying to upload image using AFNetworking & swift 3.0, but i am getting error like below.
[Cannot convert value of type '(AFMultipartFormData!) -> Void' to expected argument type '((AFMultipartFormData?) -> Void)!'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMdVQ.png)

```
    let url = "http://localhost:9000/api/content"

    var params = [
        "familyId":"10000",
        "contentBody" : "Some body content for the test application",
        "name" : "the name/title",
        "typeOfContent":"photo"
    ]

    let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()
    manager.post(
        url,
        parameters: params,
        constructingBodyWith: { (formData: AFMultipartFormData!) -> Void in
            formData.appendPartWithFileData(imageData!, name: "Photo", fileName: "photo.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
    },
        success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation?, responseObject: Any?) in

            self.onSuccess(
                operation: operation!,
                responseObject: responseObject! as AnyObject
            )
    },
        failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation?, error) in
            print("Error 1: " + error!.localizedDescription)

            self.onFailure(operation: operation)
    })
```

Does anybody know how to resolve this?
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to change the signature to the suggested / expected one?

Comment: sorry..what signature mean? @vadian

Comment: Change `(formData: AFMultipartFormData!) -> Void` *to expected argument type* `((formData: AFMultipartFormData?) -> Void)!`

Comment: @vadian Thanks dude! silly mistake!

Comment: @vadian This helped me, thanks! Swift 3 auto conversion makes things more difficult than they need to be